# How to display 10 columns records in a single column using "Group By"

Tags: sql

How can I display multiple column records as a single column using "Group By"?

So if I have this table:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
```

I want a result like this:

```
A 1,2,3
```

Comment: Totally unclear what you are asking. Please add your table structure, example data, expected output and the query you tried.

Comment: Show us what you have tried to achiveve what you want and you might get some help.

Comment: I don't agree, I think it's perfectly clear what he's asking. He should've added his DBMS though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why this question got downvoted, I think it's perfectly clear what is being asked.

It's dependant on your DBMS, but in MySQL and SQL Server you can use GROUP_CONCAT() for this.

example:

```
SELECT col1, GROUP_CONCAT(col2) FROM table1
GROUP BY col1;
```

In Oracle, we have LISTAGG() for this:

```
SELECT 
    col1,
    LISTAGG(col2, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2)
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: +1.  I have never used group_concat before.  What is the benefit of this instead of manually concatenating strings - except clearer code.